# Select ListView element after its creation

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in my Android Activity that uses a custom `BaseAdapter`, named `ClientListAdapter`, for its population.
I populate the content of this view in this AsyncTask.

```
public class MyActivity {

    […]

    ClientListAdapter clientListAdapter;

    […]

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Client client = getClient();

            List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
            clients.add(client);
            clientListAdapter = new ClientListAdapter(MyActivity.this, clients);

            return “OK";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            clientList.setAdapter(clientListAdapter);       
        }
    }

}
```

Now I want to select the first (and only) row of this ListView. And with "select" I mean:

1. Actually select with "setSelection" OR
2. Simply highlight that row, or the whole ListView.

My problem is that in the `onPostExecute` method I can't reach that row.
I tried:

`clientList.setSelection(0);` -> did nothing.

`clientList.getChildAt(0).setBackground(#somecolor);` -> there's no clientList.getChildAt(0)

`clientList.setBackground(#somecolor);` -> oddly, did nothing.

Any idea on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set the `Adapter` for `clientList`, use `post` method to set the selection, like this:

```
clientList.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        clientList.setSelection(0);
    }
});
```

Note that if you don't set a selector, you won't get a visual feedback of the selected item.